# How to allow web requests when using VCR / WebMock?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, integration-testing, vcr

I'm currently using RSpec2, Cucumber and VCR (via WebMock), and everything's working great.

With VCR normally all requests are recorded and then replayed against the recorded cassettes.

Now I want to allow real web requests in some scenarios:

- In Cucumber, I've setup a "live" profile which runs any test tagged with `@live`. For these tests – and these tests only – I'd like to allow real web requests.
- I want from time to time run the tests against the real api and ignore the recordings

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do this with cucumber's `Before` and `After` hooks. Just disable VCR using something like this:

```
Before('@live') do
  VCR.eject_cassette
  VCR.turn_off!
end
```

This may be dependent on exactly how you are integrating VCR with your cucumber tests though.

Comment: This looks promising. I'll give it a try and post back to let you know how it goes. Thanks for the help!